# Can electromagnets repel?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, voltage

So I saw a video here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wzXRFp0DDrU (See the full video first)
I don't understand that how is the electromagnet repelling things in the second half of the video? Also what is the reason for that electromagnet to be so strong? How can I make that type of electromagnet from scratch?
Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Bhavesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The electromagnet is acting as an electromagnetic ring launcher. There is [a nice explanation on YouTube here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImVIPI4ls0I), or for more about the physics see the question [Is the standard explanation for the ring launcher incomplete?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/72700/is-the-standard-explanation-for-the-ring-launcher-incomplete).

The pieces of metal are being repelled from the electromagnet because when the magnet is first turned on the changing magnetic field induces a current in the piece of metal. The current creates its own magnetic field that opposes the field of the electromagnet, and the result is that the electromagnet and the piece of metal are repelled.

This principle is used in the construction of the [Hendo hoverboard](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/142732/how-does-hendo-hoverboards-achieve-the-self-propelling-motion-what-is-the-mfa).

Comment: But why it sometimes attracts and sometimes repels. What determines if it will be a magnet or a ring launcher?